# how to make a GUI skype-like in Qt with items of contact going down

Tags: qt, skype

I tried to make a GUI like skype but without succeed. What I want is to make  list of contact the same in skype list contact. when you click on some contact in that list, we could notice that a little frame appear, contact move down like in treewidget.

I have tried Qtreewidget, listwidget (with setitemWidget function) but nothing good.

Comment: And you're talking about windows ui, linux ui or mac ui?

Comment: Also you should precise your question. Make some screens of what you want to achieve, show us code that you tried to use to make such effect

Comment: http://www.casimages.com/img.php?i=121209050447717789.png
looks at this picture: what I want is this: when you click on one item from the list of contact another widget is set at this same place like in the picture (see mouse)

Answer (score 0):

look at these classes in the Qt documentation, QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem, QTreeView and QStyledItemDelegate

Comment: the problem is not the item itself but the widget set at the place of the item.

Comment: the problem is not the item itself but the widget set at the place of the item. From QListwidget, we have this function: setItemWidget ( QListWidgetItem *, QWidget * ) and with this, we can set any widget for the item. What I want is to set dynamicaly another widget when a click occurs. say that:  I  have item A in the QListwidget and first, I set widget B for item A ( with setitemwidget) and after a click over B I want to dynamicaly sets another widget ohter than B say C for example in the same place. This another widget (C)could be greater or smaller than B

Comment: this image is taken from skype list contact, http://www.casimages.com/img.php?i=121209050447717789.png  I want to do that